# How to find contiguous subarray of integers in an array from n arrays such that the sum of elements of such contiguous subarrays is minimum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

Input: n arrays of integers of length p.

Output: An array of p integers built by copying contiguous subarrays of the input arrays into matching indices of the output, satisfying the following conditions.

- At most one subarray is used from each input array.
- Every index of the output array is filled from exactly one subarray.
- The output array has the minimum possible sum.

Suppose I have 2 arrays:

`[1,7,2]`

`[2,1,8]`

So if I choose a subarray `[1,7]` from array 1 and subarray `[8]` from array 2. since these 2 subarrays are not overlapping for any index and are contiguous. We are also not taking any subarray twice from an array from which we have already chosen a subarray.

We have the number of elements in the arrays inside the collection = `2 + 1 = 3`, which is the same as the length of the individual array (i.e. `len(array 1) which is equal to 3`). So, this collection is valid.

The sum here for `[1,7]` and `[8]` is `1 + 7 + 8 = 16`

We have to find a collection of such subarrays such that the total sum of the elements of subarrays is minimum.

A solution to the above 2 arrays would be a collection `[2,1]` from array 1 and `[2]` from array 2.
This is a valid collection and the sum is `2 + 1 + 2 = 5`  which is the minimum sum for any such collection in this case.

I cannot think of any optimal or correct approach, so I need help.

Some Ideas:

I tried a greedy approach by choosing minimum elements from all array for a particular index since the index is always increasing (non-overlapping)  after a valid choice, I don't have to bother about storing minimum value indices for every array. But this approach is clearly not correct since it will visit the same array twice.

Another method I thought was to start from the 0th index for all arrays and start storing their sum up to `k` elements for every array since the no. of arrays are finite, I can store the sum upto `k` elements in an array. Now I tried to take a minimum across these sums and for a "minimum sum", the corresponding subarray giving this sum (i.e. `k` such elements in that array) can be a candidate for a valid subarray of size `k`, thus if we take this subarray, we can add a `k + 1`-th element corresponding to every array into their corresponding sum and if the original minimum still holds, then we can keep on repeating this step. When the minima fail, we can consider the subarray up to the index for which minima holds and this will be a valid starting subarray.  However, this approach will also clearly fail because there could exist another subarray of `size < k` giving minima along with remaining index elements from our subarray of size k.

Sorting is not possible either, since if we sort then we are breaking consecutive condition.

Of course, there is a brute force method too.

I am thinking, working through a greedy approach might give a progress in the approach.

I have searched on other Stackoverflow posts, but couldn't find anything which could help my problem.

Comment: Several things are unclear here. Do all `n` input lists have the same length? If so, does the answer need to have that length too? What does "sorting is not possible" mean? - that you're not allowed to sort, or merely that you don't see a way in which sorting might help? Does every input list need to be used?

Comment: @TimPeters Yes, all input `n` input lists have the same length, the answer needs to be of the same length too. 
Sorting is not possible because we have the condition of consecutive elements.  I have made the suggested edits. Thanks

Comment: You could use `np.convolve` and adjust the kernel size iteratively, getting the indices of each entry from the kernel size to check overlapping. But that is probably more a faster brute force implementation than for a smart approach. Your optimization is in the field of combinatorics, you could try to look at ant-colony optimization or particle swarm.

Comment: Another thing that could work is Dijkstra / A* or some other graph thing, maybe filling the graph with results of np.convolve with different kernel sizes.

Comment: And something else that you could try is to just use a random walk with cached results of np.convolve for several kernel sizes. Pick four valid random integers (one for each array's kernel size, one for the position in the convolution result. Then check your overlapping condition, if valid, calculate the sum. Then pick four new random integers and compare until a better sum is found. You can check the evaluations you need for each iteration and plot that to see how it converges. This is rather fast to implement and often helps to get an idea on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Do you have any limits on n or p?

Comment: @Joe I need to understand first about how np.convolve works, then I will come back at your comment regarding using it. Also, I can see how it converges if I pick say four integers and try it using brute force. But as the size of the array grows, so does the complexity, and there might be a chance that we come across a local minimum. I will check ant-colony optimization. Thanks for your input, I will first try and see how it converges for a small input size.

Comment: @Dave I do have some limits, but I would like to learn a generalization for an arbitrarily large n and p. (say n =100000, p = 1000000)
The current problem limit is for n = 20 and p = 50.

Comment: People have been posting this question with different descriptions over and over during the past few days. Techgig codegladiators semi final round1 techgig.com/codegladiators . The problem is active till july 6th for submissions. (An accepted solution is actually posted on SO, but not under the algorithm tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, here's a recursive branch-&-bound backtracking - and potentially exhaustive - search.  Ordering heuristics can have a huge effect on how efficient these are, but without mounds of "real life" data to test against there's scant basis for picking one over another.  This incorporates what may be the single most obvious ordering rule.

Because it's a work in progress, it prints stuff as it goes along:  all solutions found, whenever they meet or beat the current best; and the index at which a search is cut off early, when that happens (because it becomes obvious that the partial solution at that point can't be extended to meet or beat the best full solution known so far).

For example,

```
>>> crunch([[5, 6, 7], [8, 0, 3], [2, 8, 7], [8, 2, 3]])
```

displays

```
new best
L2[0:1] = [2] 2
L1[1:2] = [0] 2
L3[2:3] = [3] 5
sum 5
cut at 2

L2[0:1] = [2] 2
L1[1:3] = [0, 3] 5
sum 5
cut at 2
cut at 2
cut at 2
cut at 1
cut at 1
cut at 2
cut at 2
cut at 2
cut at 1
cut at 1
cut at 1
cut at 0
cut at 0
```

So it found two ways to get a minimal sum 5, and the simple ordering heuristic was effective enough that all other paths to full solutions were cut off early.

```
def disp(lists, ixs):
    from itertools import groupby
    total = 0
    i = 0
    for k, g in groupby(ixs):
        j = i + len(list(g))
        chunk = lists[k][i:j]
        total += sum(chunk)
        print(f"L{k}[{i}:{j}] = {chunk} {total}")
        i = j

def crunch(lists):
    n = len(lists[0])
    assert all(len(L) == n for L in lists)
    # Start with a sum we know can be beat.
    smallest_sum = sum(lists[0]) + 1
    smallest_ixs = [None] * n
    ixsofar = [None] * n

    def inner(i, sumsofar, freelists):
        nonlocal smallest_sum
        assert sumsofar <= smallest_sum
        if i == n:
            print()
            if sumsofar < smallest_sum:
                smallest_sum = sumsofar
                smallest_ixs[:] = ixsofar
                print("new best")
            disp(lists, ixsofar)
            print("sum", sumsofar)
            return
        # Simple greedy heuristic: try available lists in the order
        # of smallest-to-largest at index i.
        for lix in sorted(freelists, key=lambda lix: lists[lix][i]):
            L = lists[lix]
            newsum = sumsofar
            freelists.remove(lix)
            # Try all slices in L starting at i.
            for j in range(i, n):
                newsum += L[j]
                # ">" to find all smallest answers;
                # ">=" to find just one (potentially faster)
                if newsum > smallest_sum:
                    print("cut at", j)
                    break
                ixsofar[j] = lix
                inner(j + 1, newsum, freelists)
            freelists.add(lix)

    inner(0, 0, set(range(len(lists))))
```

### How bad is brute force?

Bad. A brute force way to compute it: say there are `n` lists each with `p` elements. The code's `ixsofar` vector contains `p` integers each in `range(n)`. The only constraint is that all occurrences of any integer that appears in it must be consecutive. So a brute force way to compute the total number of such vectors is to generate *all* `p`-tuples and count the number that meet the constraints. This is woefully inefficient, taking `O(n**p)` time, but is really easy, so hard to get wrong:

```
def countb(n, p):
    from itertools import product, groupby

    result = 0
    seen = set()
    for t in product(range(n), repeat=p):
        seen.clear()
        for k, g in groupby(t):
            if k in seen:
                break
            seen.add(k)
        else:
            #print(t)
            result += 1
    return result
```

For small arguments, we can use that as a sanity check on the next function, which is efficient. This builds on common "stars and bars" combinatorial arguments to deduce the result:

```
def count(n, p):
    # n lists of length p
    # for r regions, r from 1 through min(p, n)
    # number of ways to split up: comb((p - r) + r - 1, r - 1)
    # for each, ff(n, r) ways to spray in list indices = comb(n, r) * r!
    from math import comb, prod
    total = 0
    for r in range(1, min(n, p) + 1):
        total += comb(p-1, r-1) * prod(range(n, n-r, -1))
    return total
```

### Faster

Following is the best code I have for this so far. It builds in more "smarts" to the code I posted before. In one sense, it's very effective. For example, for randomized `p = n = 20` inputs it usually finishes within a second. That's nothing to sneeze at, since:

```
>>> count(20, 20)
1399496554158060983080
>>> _.bit_length()
71
```

That is, trying every possible way would effectively take forever. The number of cases to try doesn't even fit in a 64-bit int.

On the other hand, boost `n` (the number of lists) to 30, and it can take an hour.  At 50, I haven't seen a non-contrived case finish yet, even if left to run overnight. The combinatorial explosion eventually becomes overwhelming.

OTOH, I'm looking for *the* smallest sum, period. If you needed to solve problems like this in real life, you'd either need a much smarter approach, or settle for iterative approximation algorithms.

Note: this is still a work in progress, so isn't polished, and prints some stuff as it goes along. Mostly that's been reduced to running a "watchdog" thread that wakes up every 10 minutes to show the current state of the `ixsofar` vector.

```
def crunch(lists):
    import datetime
    now = datetime.datetime.now
    start = now()
    n = len(lists[0])
    assert all(len(L) == n for L in lists)
    # Start with a sum we know can be beat.
    smallest_sum = min(map(sum, lists)) + 1
    smallest_ixs = [None] * n
    ixsofar = [None] * n

    import threading
    def watcher(stop):
        if stop.wait(60):
            return
        lix = ixsofar[:]
        while not stop.wait(timeout=600):
            print("watch", now() - start, smallest_sum)
            nlix = ixsofar[:]
            for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(lix, nlix)):
                if a != b:
                    nlix.insert(i,"--- " + str(i) + " -->")
                    print(nlix)
                    del nlix[i]
                    break
            lix = nlix

    stop = threading.Event()
    w = threading.Thread(target=watcher, args=[stop])
    w.start()

    def inner(i, sumsofar, freelists):
        nonlocal smallest_sum
        assert sumsofar <= smallest_sum
        if i == n:
            print()
            if sumsofar < smallest_sum:
                smallest_sum = sumsofar
                smallest_ixs[:] = ixsofar
                print("new best")
            disp(lists, ixsofar)
            print("sum", sumsofar, now() - start)
            return

        # If only one input list is still free, we have to take all
        # of its tail. This code block isn't necessary, but gives a
        # minor speedup (skips layers of do-nothing calls),
        # especially when the length of the lists is greater than
        # the number of lists.
        if len(freelists) == 1:
            lix = freelists.pop()
            L = lists[lix]
            for j in range(i, n):
                ixsofar[j] = lix
                sumsofar += L[j]
                if sumsofar >= smallest_sum:
                    break
            else:
                inner(n, sumsofar, freelists)
            freelists.add(lix)
            return

        # Peek ahead. The smallest completion we could possibly get
        # would come from picking the smallest element in each
        # remaining column (restricted to the lists - rows - still
        # available). This probably isn't achievable, but is an
        # absolute lower bound on what's possible, so can be used to
        # cut off searches early.
        newsum = sumsofar
        for j in range(i, n): # pick smallest from column j
            newsum += min(lists[lix][j] for lix in freelists)
            if newsum >= smallest_sum:
                return

        # Simple greedy heuristic: try available lists in the order
        # of smallest-to-largest at index i.
        sortedlix = sorted(freelists, key=lambda lix: lists[lix][i])

        # What's the next int in the previous slice? As soon as we
        # hit an int at least that large, we can do at least as well
        # by just returning, to let the caller extend the previous
        # slice instead.
        if i:
            prev = lists[ixsofar[i-1]][i]
        else:
            prev = lists[sortedlix[-1]][i] + 1
        
        for lix in sortedlix:
            L = lists[lix]
            if prev <= L[i]:
                return
            freelists.remove(lix)
            newsum = sumsofar
            # Try all non-empty slices in L starting at i.
            for j in range(i, n):
                newsum += L[j]
                if newsum >= smallest_sum:
                    break
                ixsofar[j] = lix
                inner(j + 1, newsum, freelists)
            freelists.add(lix)

    inner(0, 0, set(range(len(lists))))
    stop.set()
    w.join()
```

### Bounded by DP

I've had a lot of fun with this :-) Here's the approach they were probably looking for, using dynamic programming (DP). I have several programs that run faster in "smallish" cases, but none that can really compete on a non-contrived 20x50 case. The runtime is `O(2**n * n**2 * p)`. Yes, that's more than exponential in `n`! But it's still a minuscule fraction of what brute force can require (see above), and is a hard upper bound.

Note: this is just a loop nest slinging machine-size integers, and using no "fancy" Python features. It would be easy to recode in C, where it would run much faster. As is, this code runs over 10x faster under PyPy (as opposed to the standard CPython interpreter).

Key insight: suppose we're going left to right, have reached column j, the last list we picked from was D, and before that we picked columns from lists A, B, and C. How can we proceed? Well, we can pick the next column from D too, and the "used" set {A, B, C} doesn't change. Or we can pick some other list E, the "used" set changes to {A, B, C, D}, and E becomes the last list we picked from.

Now in all these cases, the *details* of how we reached state "used set {A, B, C} with last list D at column j" make no difference to the collection of possible completions. It doesn't matter how many columns we picked from each, or the order in which A, B, C were used: all that matters to future choices is that A, B, and C can't be used again, and D can be but - if so - must be used immediately.

Since all ways of reaching this state have the same possible completions, the cheapest full solution must have the cheapest way of reaching this state.

So we just go left to right, one column at a time, and remember for each state in the column the smallest sum reaching that state.

This isn't cheap, but it's finite ;-) Since states are subsets of row indices, combined with (the index of) the last list used, there are `2**n * n` possible states to keep track of. In fact, there are only half that, since the way sketched above never includes the index of the last-used list in the used set, but catering to that would probably cost more than it saves.

As is, states here are *not* represented explicitly. Instead there's just a large list of sums-so-far, of length `2**n * n`. The state is implied by the list index: index `i` represents the state where:

1. `i >> n` is the index of the last-used list.
2. The last `n` bits of `i` are a bitset, where bit `2**j` is set if and only if list index `j` is in the set of used list indices.

You could, e.g., represent these by dicts mapping `(frozenset, index)` pairs to sums instead, but then memory use explodes, runtime zooms, and PyPy becomes much less effective at speeding it.

Sad but true: like most DP algorithms, this finds "the best" answer but retains scant memory of how it was reached. Adding code to allow for that is harder than what's here, and typically explodes memory requirements. Probably easiest here: write `new` to disk at the end of each outer-loop iteration, one file per column. Then memory use isn't affected. When it's done, those files can be read back in again, in reverse order, and mildly tedious code can reconstruct the path it must have taken to reach the winning state, working backwards one column at a time from the end.

```
def dumbdp(lists):
    import datetime
    _min = min

    now = datetime.datetime.now
    start = now()

    n = len(lists)
    p = len(lists[0])
    assert all(len(L) == p for L in lists)
    rangen = range(n)
    USEDMASK = (1 << n) - 1
    HUGE = sum(sum(L) for L in lists) + 1

    new = [HUGE] * (2**n * n)
    for i in rangen:
        new[i << n] = lists[i][0]

    for j in range(1, p):
        print("working on", j, now() - start)
        old = new
        new = [HUGE] * (2**n * n)
        for key, g in enumerate(old):
            if g == HUGE:
                continue
            i = key >> n
            new[key] = _min(new[key], g + lists[i][j])
            newused = (key & USEDMASK) | (1 << i)
            for i in rangen:
                mask = 1 << i
                if newused & mask == 0:
                    newkey = newused | (i << n)
                    new[newkey] = _min(new[newkey],
                                       g + lists[i][j])
    result = min(new)
    print("DONE", result, now() - start)
    return result
```

Comment: Hello. I am having a very hard time understanding the code.  Can you please explain a bit about what is going on after this loop `for lix in sorted(freelists, key = lambda lix : lists[lix][i])`? Just some hints about that section would suffice. I tried visualizing it step by step, but I am lost. It would be really helpful if you can provide a short overview of that part. Thank You

Comment: Not worth it ;-) I can add enhancements that greatly speed this, but it remains heavily exponential-time in bad cases. I was hoping someone else would chime in with a clever insight. The outer loop picks an index (`lix`) of an input list (`L = lists[lix]`) to try. The inner loop then tries, one at a time, all non-empty slices of `L` beginning at index `i`: `L[i : i+1]`, `L[i : i+2]`, ..., `L[i : n]`. Recursion then tries to extend that partial solution with the input lists that are not already in use (indices still in set `freelists`), starting immediately after the slice of `L` just picked.

Comment: Note the solution is _not_ explicitly constructed. It's implicit, `solution[i] = lists[ixsofar[i]][i]`.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. It took a while for me to fully learn it since I was not crystal with the method, and it makes all sense now! I was wondering, we can't use any probabilistic approach to speed up the process for a large `n` right. since we need to take every element into consideration?

Comment: I don't know of an approach that would _usefully_ employ probability without giving up a guarantee of finding an optimal solution. Although, e.g., you could run a randomized optimization algorithm in parallel, and when it stumbled into a new best replace the deterministic algorithm's `smallest_sum` with that (the smaller that gets, the more branches can be cut off early)..As is, this program spends most of its time in the "peek ahead" calculation, which can still be sped a lot - but that's a constant-factor thing, not an `O()` thing.

Comment: Note: I just added a dynamic programming approach at the end, which is probably what the problem posers had in mind.